Given $k$ colors, how many vertices can be pre-colored such that we can guarantee that no more than $k$ colors are needed?
Let $F$ be a forest. Assume that the greedy-coloring algorithm is used, (correctly), to "pre-color" $n$ vertices. Given $k$ colors, how big can $n$ be such that there is always a way to color $F$ with at most $k$ colors?
Let's first assume that $k=2$, or rather the chromatic number of a forest. It follows that $n$ cannot be greater than $1$ from this forest (let "$0$" be vertices without a color, and "-" be edges): $0-0-0-0$, pre-color two vertices: $1-0-0-1$. No matter how we complete the coloring, a third color is always needed if this graph is to be colored completely. So $n$ is less than $2$. It's also trivial to show that $n$ can be $1$.
But what about the general case? What kind of relation between $k$ and $n$ can be established? Is there a relationship between $k$ and $n$?
I have played around a bit with how many pre-colored vertices are needed to create certain
colors, but I do not know if that is the right approach.
Any tips or leads would be helpful, thank you!

Here are some hints.

It's easy to show that if at most one vertex of a tree is precoloured, and each other vertex has a list of two permitted colours, we can complete the colouring from the lists.
This means we need to make sure our precolouring forces the colour of two vertices with an uncoloured path between them.
In order for the greedy algorithm to give a vertex colour $r$, we must have already coloured neighbours with colours $1,\ldots,r-1$. Since the graph is a forest, there can be no interaction between the colourings leading up to giving each neighbour the required colour.


My thinking leads me to this formula: $n<2^{k}-2$. Is this correct? I base it on the fact that the color $r$ needs to encounter every color $1,...,r-1$ as you mentioned, but also the fact that we don't need to fill in the $r$ and $r-1$ colored vertices.
